# Adding words in a string with a for cycle

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to change my link with each single airport and list_date. But I obtain this output:

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-10/2021-08-11

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-11/2021-08-12021-08-10/2021-08-11

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-10/2021-08-11

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-11/2021-08-12021-08-10/2021-08-11

I'd like to obtain:

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-10/2021-08-11

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-11/2021-08-12

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-10/2021-08-11

https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-11/2021-08-12

```
    list_airports = ['BCN', 'REU', 'RMU', 'VLC', 'IBZ', 'ALC', 'AGP', 'MAD']
    list_date = ['2021-08-10/2021-08-11', '2021-08-11/2021-08-12' ]
    link = "https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210809,20210831"
    
    for airport in list_airports:
         new_link = link.replace('anywhere', airport, 1)
         new_link = new_link[:-16]

         for date in list_date:
               new_link = new_link.replace('2', date, 1)
               print(new_link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

```
list_airports = ['BCN', 'REU', 'RMU', 'VLC', 'IBZ', 'ALC', 'AGP', 'MAD']
list_date = ['2021-08-10/2021-08-11', '2021-08-11/2021-08-12' ]

for airport in list_airports:
    for date in list_date:
        print( f"https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-{airport}/{date}")
```

Output:

```
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-RMU/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-RMU/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-VLC/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-VLC/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-IBZ/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-IBZ/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-ALC/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-ALC/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-AGP/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-AGP/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-MAD/2021-08-10/2021-08-11
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-MAD/2021-08-11/2021-08-12
```

Change the "print" to a "yield", and you can make this an easy-to-use function that returns a generator.